# MongoDB won't start when i use multiple ip adresses

Tags: mongodb

When I add an ip address to my MongoDB config file it won't start. When I only use 1 ip address (127.0.0.1) then there is no problem. Does someone know what im doing wrong?

My config file:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.2.1


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

And this is my log file

```
2016-06-16T12:57:32.007+0200 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2016-06-16T12:57:32.007+0200 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2016-06-16T12:57:32.009+0200 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2016-06-16T12:57:32.009+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-06-16T12:57:32.009+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 6
2016-06-16T12:57:32.009+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2016-06-16T12:57:32.009+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2016-06-16T12:57:32.010+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-06-16T12:57:32.010+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2016-06-16T12:57:32.010+0200 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2016-06-16T12:57:32.072+0200 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2016-06-16T12:57:32.072+0200 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] dbexit:  rc: 0
2016-06-16T12:57:32.106+0200 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2016-06-16T12:57:32.110+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1689 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=***-***-***-***
2016-06-16T12:57:32.110+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.7
2016-06-16T12:57:32.110+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 4249c1d2b5999ebbf1fdf3bc0e0e3b3ff5c0aaf2
2016-06-16T12:57:32.110+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
2016-06-16T12:57:32.110+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-06-16T12:57:32.110+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-06-16T12:57:32.110+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-06-16T12:57:32.110+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-06-16T12:57:32.110+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-06-16T12:57:32.110+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-06-16T12:57:32.110+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1,192.168.2.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log", quiet: true } }
2016-06-16T12:57:32.133+0200 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:99 Cannot assign requested address for socket: 192.168.2.1:27017
2016-06-16T12:57:32.133+0200 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2016-06-16T12:57:32.133+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

If there is more info needed just let me know.

Thanks!

--edit--

I tried to change `127.0.0.1,192.168.2.1` to `[127.0.0.1,192.168.2.1]` (added the brackets). Now the server does start, but its accessible from everywhere...

Comment: is IP `192.168.2.1`  of your local machine? if yes, you can not listen on same port 27017 twice. Try using different IP address.

Comment: @maximusツ Sorry I wasn't clear about the purpose, but I want to be able to connect to my DB from my house (Which is an other ip, but I used this ip so my home ip isn't visible on the website). The DB is running on my VPS.

Comment: Does mongod start if you remove 127.0.0.1 from the list?

Comment: @JamesWahlin no this doesn't work see link for new error log [link](http://pastebin.com/UgHnnwzn)

Comment: for trouble shooting, try all interfaces with `0.0.0.0`. Also, make sure iptables is not blocking.

Comment: @dman `0.0.0.0` works but I want to limit it for only a few ip address (like my home address).

Comment: I tried to change `127.0.0.1,192.168.2.1` to `[127.0.0.1,192.168.2.1]` (added the brackets). Now the server does start, but its accessible from everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

With `bindIp` you set IP where mongo will listen e.g. `192.168.2.1:27017` in your **PRIVATE** network. With `0.0.0.0` you just tell it to be open throughout your private network, you cant filter outer incoming connections with `bindIp`, you do that with firewall